# SQL Where Clause To Match Against Both Conditions Simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know how to phrase my question title for what I'm about to ask.

I have a SELECT query that must not return any rows if the **combination** of my `where` clause is true. Here is my example code:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 MyTable m1
WHERE
 (m1.User != '1' AND m1.Status != '1')
```

But what I am trying to ask SQL is:
*"only return rows when the User is not '1' AND his status is not '1' at the same time. If this **combination** is not true, then its okay to return those rows".*

So if the User is "1" and Status is "2" then that is fine to return those rows.

Seems simple but I can't visualize how to do it... help please?

Comment: Replace `AND` with `OR`

Comment: You are looking for this I guess: ` ! (m1.User = '1' OR m1.Status = '1')`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just answered my own question.... here is the answer. 'OR' doesn't test for combination of both being true.

Solution:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 MyTable m1
WHERE NOT
 (m1.User = '1' AND m1.Status = '1')
```

Because both conditions have to be true for it not to return the rows. Both = AND, Either = OR.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this using `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 MyTable m1
WHERE
 !(m1.User = '1' OR m1.Status = '1')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 MyTable m1
WHERE
 (m1.User <> '1' AND m1.Status <> '1')
```

There are many ways of doing this :)

Comment: This will not work because it will not return results if m1.User = '1' and m1.Status = '2'. I am asking it only to suppress results where BOTH are true at the same time.

Comment: This will not work because it's the same as the OP's query - which doesn't work as wanted. (the `!=` and `<>` operators are equivalent).